# Qt insert and retrieve image file from Microsoft Access

Tags: c++, qt, ms-access

So I have an image file which I would like to store in the Microsoft Access database with the OLE Object datatype. With the example from http://snipplr.com/view/40559/a-pratical-example-of-how-write-and-read-images-into-mysql-tablesusing-trolltech-qt4c/

Using Qt, I manage to store the image as a binary into the Microsoft Access DB.

```
void insertdb()
{
    QByteArray arr;
    QFile f("C:\\Users\\cerf\\Downloads\\1.jpeg");
    if (f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        arr = f.readAll();
        f.close();
    }

    QSqlDatabase::database().transaction();
    Database db; /*this is from the database class*/
    db.connect("D:\\Safebox.mdb");
    QSqlQuery *q = new QSqlQuery(db.getDatabase());
    q->prepare("INSERT INTO Table1 (image) VALUES (:image);");
    q->bindValue(":image", arr);
    q->exec();
    if (q->lastError().isValid()) 
    {
        qDebug() << q->lastError().text();
        QSqlDatabase::database().rollback();
    }
    else
        QSqlDatabase::database().commit();

    delete q;

}
```

and this is the data shown in MS Access [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZHlX.png)

But when I try to retrieve the image again, with the below snippet

```
void retrieve()
{
    QSqlDatabase::database().transaction();
    Database db;
    db.connect("D:\\Safebox.mdb");
    QSqlQuery *q = new QSqlQuery(db.getDatabase());
    q->prepare("SELECT ID, image FROM Table1 WHERE ID=:id");
    q->bindValue(":id", 21);
    q->exec();
    q->next();
    QByteArray ba1 = q->value(1).toByteArray();
    QPixmap pic;
    if (!pic.loadFromData(ba1))
        qDebug() << "load data fail";

    ui.label->setPixmap(pic);
    QSqlDatabase::database().commit();
    delete q;
}
```

qdebug shows load data fail, any idea?

Comment: `QPixmap` is meant to read raw image data. You might want to try [QImage::loadFromData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#loadFromData) instead.

Comment: Tried both actually, still the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. The code actually works, it just my image file is corrupted.